# D lodepng compilation error

Tags: image-processing, compiler-errors, d

I have some trouble compiling lodepng (http://lodev.org/lodepng/) for D into my project.

In Encode.d I have the following code, where the compiler does not expect the assert statements.
Removing this block solves the issue.

```
invariant
{
    assert(compressionLevel >=0 && compressionLevel <= 9, "invalid zlib compression level");
    assert(targetColorType == ColorType.Any ||
            targetColorType == ColorType.RGB ||
            targetColorType == ColorType.RGBA, "colortype is not supported");
}
```

In Decode.d I have even more trouble, with the error "no identifier for declarator inout(value)"
for the middle line in:

```
info.backgroundColor.length = chunk.data.length / 2;
foreach(index, inout value; info.backgroundColor)
    value = chunk.data[index * 2];
```

Is there some trouble with old syntax here, and how do I fix it?
Is there some other way to create png images in D in a simple manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up on lodepng, and used the code on
http://www.dsource.org/projects/plot2kill/browser/trunk/png.d
which works after some minor changes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the invariant problem, but the second problem should be solved by replacing the "inout" with "ref" (D2 syntax change).

Comment: I tried that, but there were too many strange errors in the code, that the compiler found after these replacements.